# Attracting fixed point of discrete multivariable dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

I have a discrete dynamical system $(Mat_n(\mathbb R), F)$ where $Mat_n(\mathbb R)$ denotes the space of $n\times n$ matrices with real entries, and $F:Mat_n(\mathbb R)\to Mat_n(\mathbb R)$ is a smooth function. The system evolves as $X_{n+1}=F(X_n)$ starting from an initialization $X_0$.

It turns out that $0$ is a fixed point. However, I am interested to know if $0$ is an attracting fixed point.

The theorems I see so far concern real valued dynamical system and derivatives of $F$ (when $F$ is real valued). My $F$ is firstly matrix valued and also a bit complicated.

What are some strategies I can try? Perhaps the very first thing is to try something like a fixed point theorem, but what is the right notion of derivative whose norm I want to show is upper bounded by 1? Is there a converse, like if the derivative norm (whatever that is) is larger than 1, then 0 is no longer an attracting fixed point?

If there is any comprehensive text that provides methods to prove such things, I would be more than grateful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If the function is a contraction under some norm for the matrices then you are done.

Comment: The way to check that is to get some sort of mean value theorem for matrix valued functions so that the derivative (whatever that is) can be upper bounded in the norm. Do we have something like that?

Comment: You want the property that $||F(A)-F(B)||\leq \rho ||A-B||$ for some $\rho \in [0, 1)$. If it works you can use, for example, $||A||^2=\sum_{i,j} a_{ij}^2$. Indeed if you treat $F:\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as a basic function of $n^2$ variables and you show $||\nabla F(x)||\leq \rho$ for all $x$ then this will suffice.

Comment: Thanks. I am interested to understand the behavior at 0, so is it enough to consider only $B=0$?